# name is not recognized using standard sql bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am calculating the amount of each 'Name' and sort it out by ID in a nested query. What I did is just i put the COUNT(Name) in SELECT. However, the code returns an error that it does not recognize column 'Name' as the FROM is in the inner statement.  My code is :

```
SELECT
   User_ID, 
    COUNT(Name) AS Total,

 SUM(CASE WHEN Language = 'EN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EN,

 FROM (
   SELECT 
    User_ID, 

      CASE 
        WHEN Language in ('EN', 'English') THEN 'EN' 
        WHEN Language in ('MY', 'Malay')  THEN 'MY' ELSE Language 
      END AS Language,

   FROM 'table'
   GROUP BY User_ID, Language
 )
 GROUP BY User_ID
```

What should I fix to remove the error?

Comment: Your subquery returns no name column.

Comment: BTW, why the GROUP BY in the subquery when no aggregate function is used? Do you simply want SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: You should ask a new question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.  Even if you fix the `name` problem, You have other errors and your intent is not clear.

Comment: yes, will do thanks :) this question is quite general so none of the answers answered it, thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure to add the 'Name' column in your sub query.

Obviously you would have to group by 'Name' as well once you add it.

```
SELECT
 User_ID, 
 COUNT(Name) AS Total,
 SUM(CASE WHEN Language = 'EN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EN,

 FROM (
  SELECT 
  User_ID, 
  Name,

   CASE 
     WHEN Language in ('EN', 'English') THEN 'EN' 
     WHEN Language in ('MY', 'Malay')  THEN 'MY' ELSE Language 
   END AS Language,

  FROM 'table'
  GROUP BY User_ID, Name, Language
 )
GROUP BY User_ID
```

Try this.

Comment: I've tried this before. the number of Name should be equivalent to the number of Language. However, when I added the GROUP BY Name, the number is not equivalent to the number of Language. Not sure why

Comment: @swm what do you mean with that? Why the number of names should be the same of number of languages?

Comment: @swm Can you post your query result and the actual expected result? It could help finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a `Name` column to count things. This should be correct:

```sql
SELECT T.User_ID, COUNT(*) AS Total, SUM(CASE WHEN T.Language = 'EN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EN
FROM (
   SELECT User_ID,
      CASE 
        WHEN Language in ('EN', 'English') THEN 'EN' 
        WHEN Language in ('MY', 'Malay')  THEN 'MY'
        ELSE Language 
      END AS Language
   FROM 'table'
   GROUP BY User_ID, Language
) AS T
GROUP BY T.User_ID
```

I can't tell for BigQuery, but relational databases require aliasing subqueries, so I've aliased yours as `T`.

There also has been a redundant comma after `SUM(CASE WHEN Language = 'EN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EN,`